# Firefox Browser and Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, firefox

Firefox comes with Ubuntu. My version is 16.04 LTS. Installed yesterday. But when I run Firefox why does the browser connects or try to connect with multiple websites before connecting to the one chosen? It connects or tries to connect with ten or twelve sites slowing down  the time to connect and using up resource AND possibly sending data info to all these sites.One was google ananlytics and one was even PayPal.

So this brings the question of an alternative browser for Ubuntu and/or add ons or extensions to add to the Firefox browser. I have never seen it this bad and wonder if its something inherent in Ubunti or Firefox? Never seen this running Windows 7 with Google Chrome.

Comment: If you did not manually install any addons, that menas that you installed some customized Ubuntu fork.

Comment: Try chromium its add free, so I am told.

Comment: Since reading your comment I added Ghostery to Firefox and that stopped all the sites from appearing in the address window. One website there were 52 trackers! I am going to look into Chromium also. I was not aware it was non Google. What do you think of the ex CEO of Mozilla with his new BRAVE Browser for Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is connecting to those other servers because the web page calls for it.  The stuff that is being loaded from the other servers is mostly related to advertising and such.  Your browser could be downloading code for the page, i.e. some kind of "widget" that provides site functionality, like the button that connects you to Twitter so you can send a tweet about the page, or it could be logging your visit to the page for statistical purposes (Google Analytics), or it could be downloading an ad.  All major browsers download the same stuff from the same servers when you load the same page, otherwise the page would look and behave very differently in different browsers.  The difference in this case between Firefox on Ubuntu and Chrome on Windows 7 is that the developers of Firefox decided to notify you about all the different places the page asks the browser to download from, and the developers of Chrome decided not to; but Chrome is downloading that stuff also, even though it's not telling you about it.

You could download a different browser if you don't want to know about all that stuff, but chances are your page load times will be similar.  If your goal is faster page load times, you'll probably see more improvement from downloading a browser extension that blocks cookies or ads.

Answer (score 0):

There are literally too many browsers to list:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsers
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/web-browsers/

I personally use Chrome, and Firefox as a backup. If I couldn't use Firefox, I'd try Chromium (which is not chrome). I've heard it's okay too.

The second issue is that this is definitely not normal behavior for Firefox, given that I have almost no information about your system.

If I were you, I'd seriously look at what's going on, especially if it's accessing your paypal.

Comment: Going to find the area, Profiles?, where I can put my system info for yourself and others. As posted in above comment what do you think of the browser BRAVE?

Comment: I haven't tried it. I personally stick to very-well tested applications, unless there aren't any other options. When something goes wrong, there's just a lot more google-able help. That's not to say my way is the only way. Basically, YMMV.

Comment: In regards to system specs, I don't know if there are any really elegant ways. I would just include it in the post. If you can't edit it, you can always comment with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, when I had just installed this Ubuntu version.

To solve it, I had just updated Firefox, it was 2 versions late and installed an [adblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/). Now it works just fine and lighter than Chrome.

Suggestion:
[With these addons you can have a great experience without performance issues. You can find them at the same place as the Adblock.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdPol.jpg)